# How to delete gnome-contacts or evolution data?

Tags: gnome, evolution

I have tried

```
rm ~/.local/share/evolution/addressbook/system/contacts.db
```

at no avail (contacts still visible in gnome-contacts), then

```
rm -rf /home/alba/.local/share/evolution/
rm -rf .cache/evolution
```

at no avail.

The only effect is to make contacts uneditable and throw this error

```
Cannot modify contacts: SQLite error code `8': attempt to write a readonly database
```

Therefrom I guess there is some sort of database elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the file but I opened Evolution Contacts, selected all and deleted.